# Add caption to figure which has subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add some text to a figure. I've read a few posts on the matter, but the answers don't seem to work when the figure has subplots.

**Example:**
I would like the text to not overlap any images.
[image]

**Code:**

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bincount = 100
mean, stdev, population = 0, 1, 10000
separation = 3*stdev

norm1 = numpy.random.normal(mean, stdev, population)
norm2 = numpy.random.normal(mean + separation, stdev, population)
comb = numpy.concatenate([norm1, norm2]) #concatenate nd_arrays

plt.figure("Bayesian")
plt.subplot(313)
plt.title("Combined")
hist3 = plt.hist(comb, bincount) #population, bins, patch = plt.hist()

plt.subplot(221)
plt.title("Class 1")
hist1 = plt.hist(norm1, bins=hist3[1])

plt.subplot(222)
plt.title("Class 2")
hist2 = plt.hist(norm2, bins=hist3[1])

index = int(len(hist3[1])/2)#arbitrarily choosing the middle bin
bin = hist3[1][index]
binsize = (max(hist3[1])-min(hist3[1]))/len(hist3[1])
probIndex = 1/len(hist3[1])
probClass = len(norm1)/len(comb)
condProbClass = hist1[0][index]/sum(hist1[0])
condProbIndex = probClass*condProbClass/probIndex

t = "An item is found at index {idx}, which corresponds to {binStart}-{binEnd}. What is the probabilty it belongs to class 1?\n\n"\
    "Given this, the probability of any item being Class 1 is {pC1}\n"\
    "The probabilty of any item being found at index {idx} is {pInd}\n"\
    "The conditional probability of the item falling in this index given it belongs to class 1 is {cpC1}\n"\
    "Using Bayes-Theorem, we can now find the probability of an item found at this index belongs to class 1 is {cpI}"\
    .format(
    idx=index,
    binStart=bin-binsize/2,
    binEnd=bin+binsize/2,
    pC1=probClass,
    pInd=probIndex,
    cpC1=condProbClass,
    cpI=condProbIndex
)

plt.figtext(0, 0, t, wrap=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try to put the text caption in a new empty subplot at the bottom?

Comment: It's still acting weird for me. At least now I know how the subplot parameter works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the subplot2grid function, you can leave empty space at the bottom for the text.  Make sure to call `plt.tight_layout()` so that your axes don't overlap.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bincount = 100
mean, stdev, population = 0, 1, 10000
separation = 3*stdev

norm1 = numpy.random.normal(mean, stdev, population)
norm2 = numpy.random.normal(mean + separation, stdev, population)
comb = numpy.concatenate([norm1, norm2]) #concatenate nd_arrays

fig = plt.figure("Bayesian")

plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (2, 0), colspan=4, rowspan=1)
plt.title("Combined")
hist3 = plt.hist(comb, bincount) #population, bins, patch = plt.hist()

plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
plt.title("Class 1")
hist1 = plt.hist(norm1, bins=hist3[1])

plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 2), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
plt.title("Class 2")
hist2 = plt.hist(norm2, bins=hist3[1])

index = int(len(hist3[1])/2)#arbitrarily choosing the middle bin
bin = hist3[1][index]
binsize = (max(hist3[1])-min(hist3[1]))/len(hist3[1])
probIndex = 1/len(hist3[1])
probClass = len(norm1)/len(comb)
condProbClass = hist1[0][index]/sum(hist1[0])
condProbIndex = probClass*condProbClass/probIndex

t = "An item is found at index {idx}, which corresponds to {binStart}-{binEnd}. What is the probabilty it belongs to class 1?\n\n"\
    "Given this, the probability of any item being Class 1 is {pC1}\n"\
    "The probabilty of any item being found at index {idx} is {pInd}\n"\
    "The conditional probability of the item falling in this index given it belongs to class 1 is {cpC1}\n"\
    "Using Bayes-Theorem, we can now find the probability of an item found at this index belongs to class 1 is {cpI}"\
    .format(
    idx=index,
    binStart=bin-binsize/2,
    binEnd=bin+binsize/2,
    pC1=probClass,
    pInd=probIndex,
    cpC1=condProbClass,
    cpI=condProbIndex
)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.figtext(0, 0, t, wrap=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)` to adjust the bottom position for your subplots. I've tried your code with different arguments and found that `0.30` works for me.

Adding the line anywhere in your code before the `show` command should make it work.